# wso2 Data Mapper Mediator error reading input stream

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting an error from my datamapper mediator. I already did this before but this time I used the conf instead of gov for my data mapper input and ouput schema.

Here my api config
http://pastebin.com/41iweHs7

Here's the error

```
ERROR - DataMapperMediator Error while reading input stream. No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4942c854; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference whether it is gov or conf. According to your error, it is due to a parse error in your input schema. Is your input type JSON or XML (your configuration says XML) ? Can you recheck whether it is the same Schema that worked earlier?

Comment: Yep, I checked my input schema type and it's correct which is XML to JSON. I even tried to play with it by changing it.